# Getting a Run-time error 424 on command button click for MS Access VBA code

Tags: vba, object, ms-access-2016

I created a button on an Access form that changes the value of column New_column to "YES" but I keep getting a run-time error 424 Object Required.  Here's the code generating the error.

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()
   New_column.Value = "YES"
End Sub
```

But if I simply change the column name to another one that accepts text (e.g., Old_column) I don't get the error.

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()
   Old_column.Value = "YES"
End Sub
```

What is the difference between New_column and Old_column that would cause one to generate the error but not the other?  Both are text fields that already contain text values.  I compared the properties for both fields and didn't see any differences.  I added New_column using an update query after some original VBA code was written, if that's a clue.

Comment: You don't add columns with an update query. In any case what matters is the control, not the column. Apparently there is no textbox named `New_column` on your form.

Comment: Thanks!  I didn't realized I was assigning a value to the text box that was holding the value of the column.  I renamed the text box to the column name and it appears to be working.